# Configure mutual TLS origination for egress traffic for more then 200 target destination with different cert requirements

Tags: istio

I've got a use case of an application that needs to authenticate with mTLS to hundreds of different destination servers outside of the mesh with a different client certificate. I thought offloading this procedure form the app to Istio is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You can follow this [guide](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway-tls-origination/) to configure mutual TLS orgination for egress traffic.

Then for each destination modify the `DestinationRule` to use different certificate like in this [example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: db-mtls
spec:
  host: mydbserver.prod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: MUTUAL
      clientCertificate: /etc/certs/myclientcert.pem
      privateKey: /etc/certs/client_private_key.pem
      caCertificates: /etc/certs/rootcacerts.pem
```

Hope it helps.